# Function patch not being picked up by imported module

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, mocking

I feel like this should be an easy mock, but I have not gotten it to work yet.

I am working off of the following directory structure:

```
module
├── utilities.py
├── order.py
├── test
│   ├── test_order.py
```

The relevant code is as follows:

## -- utilities.py --

```
def get_file_path(order_number, file_extension):
    # this is what I want to mock out
```

## -- order.py --

```
from module.utilities import get_file_path

class Order():
    # ...

    @classmethod
    def load_order(order_number, extension):
        file_path = get_file_path(order_number, extension)
```

## -- test_order.py --

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from module.order import order

@patch('order.get_file_path')
def mock_file(_, extension):
    if extension == 'json':
        return static_file_path

class TestOrder(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_load_order_by_number(self):
        my_order = order.load_order(number, extension)
```

This is the first time that I have tried mocking in Python. From what I can tell, what I have should work, but whenever an `Order` calls `get_file_path`, it always uses the one in `utilities.py`.

I have tried:

- decorating `test_load_order_by_number`
- patching with `module.order.get_file_path`

I tried looking on SO but none of the solutions that I found helped, so I thought that I was just doing something obviously wrong that someone can point out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not look like creating the patch outside of the class was getting picked up. It started working when I pulled the patch in as a decorator for the specific test.

```
class TestOrder(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('utilities.order.get_file_path')
    def test_load_order_by_number(self, file_mock):

        def mock_get_file_path(*args, **kwargs):
            if kwargs.get('extension', None) == 'json':
                return static_file_path
            return None

        file_mock.side_effect = mock_get_file_path

        my_order = order.load_order(number, extension)
```